# How to set xml value with attribute

Tags: xml, go

I believe it should be easy, but I can not find the solution.

```
type Data struct {
    ItemA string `xml:"item-string"`
    ItemB Item
}

type Item struct {
    XMLName   xml.Name      `xml:"item-struct"`
    Type     string         `xml:"type,attr"`
}

func Test() {
    itm := Data {
        ItemA: "good",
        ItemB: Item {
            Type: "nice",
        },
    }
    output, err := xml.MarshalIndent(&itm,"","    ")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    result := string(output)
    fmt.Printf("\n%s\n",result)
}
```

I get formated xml data:

```
<Data>
    <item-string>good</item-string>
    <item-struct type="nice"></item-struct>
</Data>
```

How do I set or add value to item-struct, to get this:

```
<Data>
    <item-string>good</item-string>
    <item-struct type="nice">very good</item-struct>
</Data>
```

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/h2sGWnGpWXI

Answer (score 0):

You can try `innerxml` tag.

```
- a field with tag ",innerxml" is written verbatim, not subject
  to the usual marshaling procedure.
```

more details is here: https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml

change your code to this:

```
type Data struct {
    ItemA string `xml:"item-string"`
    ItemB Item
}

type Item struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"item-struct"`
    Type    string   `xml:"type,attr"`
    Value   string   `xml:",innerxml"`
}

func TestData(t *testing.T) {
    itm := Data{
        ItemA: "good",
        ItemB: Item{
            Type:  "nice",
            Value: "very good",
        },
    }
    output, err := xml.MarshalIndent(&itm, "", "    ")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    result := string(output)
    fmt.Printf("\n%s\n", result)
}
```

output will like this

```xml
<Data>
    <item-string>good</item-string>
    <item-struct type="nice">very good</item-struct>
</Data>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working example by mkopriva in the comment

https://play.golang.org/p/h2sGWnGpWXI

is the answer